# Excel numbers combination

Tags: excel, numbers, combinations, formula

Can anyone help me create 70 different combinations of 5 numbers including 1 to 75 on Excel?

I have tried this one:

**=LARGE(ROW($1:$75)*NOT(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,ROW($1:$75))),RANDBETWEEN(1,(75+2-1)-ROW(A2)))**

unfortunately in the combinations there are many zeros. How can I make it so it will not have zeros?

example

2,39,45,12,14

74,23,8,40,66

1,7,29,39,11.

Comment: The number `40` has a zero in it.  Is this acceptable?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 40 is part of the range 1 to 75. When I enter the formula on Excel it also gives me the 0 itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have written you a macro

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim number As Integer
number = 0
Dim total As Integer
total = 0
For i = 1 To 70
    For j = 1 To 5
        Cells(i, j).Value = 0
    Next j
Next i
For i = 1 To 70
    total = 0
    For j = 1 To 5
        Cells(i, j).Value = Int((75) * Rnd + 1)
        total = total + Cells(i, j).Value
    Next j
    For k = i + 1 To 70
        number = 0
        For m = 1 To 5
            number = number + Cells(k, m).Value
        Next m
        If number = total And number > 0 Then
            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next k
Next i
End Sub
```

I must apologise that my code is slightly illogical as checking the sum of each row will eliminate some combinations which would have been different but it does guarantee uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

In A1:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,15)
```

In B1 and copied across to E1:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(A1+1,15*column())
```

Copy down A1:E1 to A100, select all, Paste Special Values over the top Remove Duplicates and delete rows 71 onwards.